# Error with Django Celery ,how to fix?

Tags: django, celery, django-celery, celery-task

well i have same view same setting for celery in another app, when i launch another one, he is work, absolutely work, but when i launch this, nothing, i installed everthyng like in another one, but nothing, pls help me!

if you have some ideas how to fix please let me know)

This is full traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\P.A.N.D.E.M.I.C\Desktop\shop\lib\site-packages\kombu\utils\__init__.py", line 423, in __call__
    return self.__value__
AttributeError: 'ChannelPromise' object has no attribute '__value__'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\P.A.N.D.E.M.I.C\Desktop\shop\lib\site-packages\kombu\connection.py", line 449, in _ensured
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\P.A.N.D.E.M.I.C\Desktop\shop\lib\site-packages\kombu\messaging.py", line 177, in _publish
    channel = self.channel
  File "C:\Users\P.A.N.D.E.M.I.C\Desktop\shop\lib\site-packages\kombu\messaging.py", line 194, in _get_channel
    channel = self._channel = channel()
  File "C:\Users\P.A.N.D.E.M.I.C\Desktop\shop\lib\site-packages\kombu\utils\__init__.py", line 425, in __call__
    value = self.__value__ = self.__contract__()
  File "C:\Users\P.A.N.D.E.M.I.C\Desktop\shop\lib\site-packages\kombu\messaging.py", line 209, in <lambda>
    channel = ChannelPromise(lambda: connection.default_channel)
  File "C:\Users\P.A.N.D.E.M.I.C\Desktop\shop\lib\site-packages\kombu\connection.py", line 771, in default_channel
    self.connection
  File "C:\Users\P.A.N.D.E.M.I.C\Desktop\shop\lib\site-packages\kombu\connection.py", line 756, in connection
    self._connection = self._establish_connection()
  File "C:\Users\P.A.N.D.E.M.I.C\Desktop\shop\lib\site-packages\kombu\connection.py", line 711, in _establish_connection
    conn = self.transport.establish_connection()
  File "C:\Users\P.A.N.D.E.M.I.C\Desktop\shop\lib\site-packages\kombu\transport\pyamqp.py", line 116, in establish_connection
    conn = self.Connection(**opts)
  File "C:\Users\P.A.N.D.E.M.I.C\Desktop\shop\lib\site-packages\amqp\connection.py", line 165, in __init__
    self.transport = self.Transport(host, connect_timeout, ssl)
  File "C:\Users\P.A.N.D.E.M.I.C\Desktop\shop\lib\site-packages\amqp\connection.py", line 186, in Transport
    return create_transport(host, connect_timeout, ssl)
  File "C:\Users\P.A.N.D.E.M.I.C\Desktop\shop\lib\site-packages\amqp\transport.py", line 299, in create_transport
    return TCPTransport(host, connect_timeout)
  File "C:\Users\P.A.N.D.E.M.I.C\Desktop\shop\lib\site-packages\amqp\transport.py", line 95, in __init__
    raise socket.error(last_err)
OSError: [WinError 10061]The connection is not established, because the destination computer rejected the connection request 

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\P.A.N.D.E.M.I.C\Desktop\shop\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\P.A.N.D.E.M.I.C\Desktop\shop\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\P.A.N.D.E.M.I.C\Desktop\shop\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\P.A.N.D.E.M.I.C\Desktop\shop\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 149, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\P.A.N.D.E.M.I.C\Desktop\shop\src\accounts\decorators.py", line 25, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\P.A.N.D.E.M.I.C\Desktop\shop\src\accounts\views.py", line 41, in signup
    register_task.delay(username, password, email, get_secret_key)
  File "C:\Users\P.A.N.D.E.M.I.C\Desktop\shop\lib\site-packages\celery\app\task.py", line 453, in delay
    return self.apply_async(args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\P.A.N.D.E.M.I.C\Desktop\shop\lib\site-packages\celery\app\task.py", line 559, in apply_async
    **dict(self._get_exec_options(), **options)
  File "C:\Users\P.A.N.D.E.M.I.C\Desktop\shop\lib\site-packages\celery\app\base.py", line 353, in send_task
    reply_to=reply_to or self.oid, **options
  File "C:\Users\P.A.N.D.E.M.I.C\Desktop\shop\lib\site-packages\celery\app\amqp.py", line 305, in publish_task
    **kwargs
  File "C:\Users\P.A.N.D.E.M.I.C\Desktop\shop\lib\site-packages\kombu\messaging.py", line 172, in publish
    routing_key, mandatory, immediate, exchange, declare)
  File "C:\Users\P.A.N.D.E.M.I.C\Desktop\shop\lib\site-packages\kombu\connection.py", line 470, in _ensured
    interval_max)
  File "C:\Users\P.A.N.D.E.M.I.C\Desktop\shop\lib\site-packages\kombu\connection.py", line 382, in ensure_connection
    interval_start, interval_step, interval_max, callback)
  File "C:\Users\P.A.N.D.E.M.I.C\Desktop\shop\lib\site-packages\kombu\utils\__init__.py", line 246, in retry_over_time
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\P.A.N.D.E.M.I.C\Desktop\shop\lib\site-packages\kombu\connection.py", line 250, in connect
    return self.connection
  File "C:\Users\P.A.N.D.E.M.I.C\Desktop\shop\lib\site-packages\kombu\connection.py", line 756, in connection
    self._connection = self._establish_connection()
  File "C:\Users\P.A.N.D.E.M.I.C\Desktop\shop\lib\site-packages\kombu\connection.py", line 711, in _establish_connection
    conn = self.transport.establish_connection()
  File "C:\Users\P.A.N.D.E.M.I.C\Desktop\shop\lib\site-packages\kombu\transport\pyamqp.py", line 116, in establish_connection
    conn = self.Connection(**opts)
  File "C:\Users\P.A.N.D.E.M.I.C\Desktop\shop\lib\site-packages\amqp\connection.py", line 165, in __init__
    self.transport = self.Transport(host, connect_timeout, ssl)
  File "C:\Users\P.A.N.D.E.M.I.C\Desktop\shop\lib\site-packages\amqp\connection.py", line 186, in Transport
    return create_transport(host, connect_timeout, ssl)
  File "C:\Users\P.A.N.D.E.M.I.C\Desktop\shop\lib\site-packages\amqp\transport.py", line 299, in create_transport
    return TCPTransport(host, connect_timeout)
  File "C:\Users\P.A.N.D.E.M.I.C\Desktop\shop\lib\site-packages\amqp\transport.py", line 95, in __init__
    raise socket.error(last_err)
OSError: [WinError 10061] `The connection is not established, because the destination computer rejected the connection request`
```

this is celery

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'src.settings')

from django.conf import settings
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('src')

# This reads, e.g., CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json'] from settings.py:
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')

# For autodiscover_tasks to work, you must define your tasks in a file called 'tasks.py'.
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)

@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print("Request: {0!r}".format(self.request))
```

this is settings

```
# CELERY STUFF
BROKER_URL                  = 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND       = 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT       = ['application/json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER      = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER    = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE            = TIME_ZONE
```

this is view

```
@csrf_protect
@check_recaptcha
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        print(form)
        if form.is_valid() and request.recaptcha_is_valid:
            print(form.cleaned_data)
            email               = form.cleaned_data['email']
            username            = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password            = form.cleaned_data['password1']
            get_secret_key      = activation_key_generator(username)
            link                = "127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/activate/{0}".format(get_secret_key)
            html_message        = '<h3>Your username: <b>{0}</b> <br> <b>Your password:  <b>{1}</b></h3><br><h1>That to get full access to our services, go through link below!</h1> <br> <a href="{2}">Activate</a> need raw link? <br> {2}'.format(username, password, link)
            register_task.delay(username, password, email, get_secret_key)
            send_some_email_task.delay(email, username, html_message)
            return redirect('/accounts/register/verification')
    form = RegistrationForm(request.POST or None)
    context = {'form':form}

    return render(request, 'accounts/registration/signup.html', context)
```

Comment: What's the Russian error message? Are you sure RabbitMQ is running and you can connect to its ports?

Comment: The connection is not established, because the destination computer rejected the connection request

Comment: Well can you telnet to the ports? Is RabbitMQ running?

Comment: yea, backend='aqmp' it's from rabbitmq , but works with it exactly, that's with version 3.1.18, the thing is that absolutely the same settings are the targets on the other application works! I can show it in skype

Comment: i using redis, just in tutor was this, so and i included it )

Answer (score -1):

You said in the comments you are using Redis but the configuration you have is for RabbitMQ. Check [Using Redis](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/redis.html) page for more info on configuration. More specifically, your broker URL should be something like `redis://:password@hostname:port/db_number`, not amqp.

Comment: Have you read the description? did you read trakebask? How can your answer fix my mistake?